# sql error how to fix it

Tags: php, sql

I am running this sql in php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".TABLE_PREMIUM." (Installation_ID, Purchase_ID, Enabled, Expired, Updated) VALUES('$installation', '$product', '1','$expiry', now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Installation_ID='$installation, Purchase_ID='$product', Enabled = '1', Expired = '$expiry', Updated = now() ";
```

And I keep getting this error

> ```
> INSERT INTO Premium (Installation_ID, Purchase_ID, Enabled, Expired,
> Updated) VALUES('123456', '1111.22222222.3333.44444', '1','2016-05-13
> 11:10:09', now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Installation_ID='123456,
> Purchase_ID='1111.22222222.3333.44444', Enabled = '1', Expired =
> '2016-05-13 11:10:09', Updated = 2015-03-03 11:11:11
> ```
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1111.22222222.3333.44444', Enabled = '1', Expired = '2016-05-13
>   11:10:09', Updat' at line 1

What could be the issue? I can't decode it from this error

Comment: you may be missing a quote right after '$installation -- before the comma --- causing data to be concatenated.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: notice anything different between these two? `Expired = '2016-05-13 11:10:09', Updated = 2015-03-03 11:11:11`

Comment: Do you see a problem now? Everything is color-coded.

Comment: Check you quotes. `Installation_ID` and `Updated`

Comment: Missing single quote here, `... Installation_ID='$installation, Purchase_ID= ...`

Comment: There are probably other problems with data types that we can't see without the table details.  Some fields appear they should be numeric.

Comment: it was the single quote missing from installation ID. :) I can't believe I couldnt see it.  Not sure why people would downvote. It happens that someone would do silly mistake. It is not worth downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `'` **(single quote)** after `UPDATE Installation_ID='$installation`

Comment: Yes the missing quote was it :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the purchase ID is too much long or it can be that you're missing a ' after installation_id = '$installation maybe that could be the problem.

Comment: Yes the missing quote was it, but bns answered it before you so I accepted his answer. Thanks